# How to split 1 column in excel to many column

Tags: excel

I have only 1 column in excel, about 40,000 cells, I need to split them into 150 column length. 
So colum A, B, C.... Will be 150 cells each of them.

Searching about this on Google i found only how to split 1 sell into many cells.

I have tried it, it only can convert the text of 1 cell to 2 cells..

What i want is how to remain each cell as it is. But re arrange them.

If this option is not found in excel.. Is there any other solution.. Such as convert it to Access arrange the data then convert it to excel?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you give us an example of how your excel looks like, and how you would like it to look? It will make answering this question easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column A starting at A1, copy this into B1:B150 and then copy to the right as many columns as needed:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,((COLUMN()-2)*150)+(ROW()))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data starting in A1, select B1:B150 and enter this array formula:

```
 =OFFSET($A$1;150*(COLUMNS($B$1:B$1)-1);0;150;1)
```

Dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter

Now copy right as many times as you need

Comment: Copying right would probably be better :). Also, note that you don't need the volatile `Offset` function or an array formula.

Comment: Hehehe....sure copy right :) ... This is to use one time, dont think there is any problem... and array formulas exist, no problem in using them.... :)

Comment: I like array formulas, but only use them when needed, because of the issue of forgetting to re-enter as array next time.

Comment: OK, if you forget it you immediately remember when you see the wrong result :)